# Standard design steps for C++ Expression Templates,how to design?

Tags: c++, optimization, metaprogramming

I'm learning C++ Expression Templates these days, I've read a lot of articles. Still confused about how to design an express template.

Is there any standard way(steps) when we design Expression Templates, in other words , how to design, including what classes should I create and what operations should I performed in specific functions?

Let's say Matrix computations.

I know how to write it via overloading C++ operators, but after I finish it by overloading coperators I don't know how to write it using Expression Templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea of having an expression template is to use lazy evaluation, i.e. only compute result when using an expression that uses the addition, subtraction, etc. expression for specific index, instead of computing the result for all the values of the arrays in the constructor.

1. Have a "sum" class with two variable members, where each represent the arrays that you want to add (As you add more than two arrays, this class will be used "recursively" as I'll show below). For this you need to have a class with 2 template arguments for each member, and have an `operator[]` which returns the addition of both arrays for specific location, i.e.

   ```
   int operator[](const int i) const
   {
     return a[i] + b[i];
   }
   ```
2. Have a "starting" class which initializes the values of your arrays. Note that this class is different from the above, as it will only store 1 array. Also this class must implement `operator[]` as follows:

   ```
   int operator[](const int i) const
   {
     return starting_vector[i];
   }
   ```
3. Have an overload `operator+` to add your "starting" vector (from 2 bullet) with other ones, and to store them in the "sum" class (from 1 bullet) as:

   ```
   template <typename A, typename B>
   VectorSum<A, B> operator+(const A v1, const B v2)
   {
     return VectorSum<A, B>{v1, v2};
   }
   ```

Below is a complete example that compiles:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

class Vector
{
  public:

    explicit Vector(const std::initializer_list<int>& vec)
    {
      for (const auto x : vec)
      {
        starting_vector.push_back(x);
      }
    }

    int operator[](const int i) const
    {
      return starting_vector[i];
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
      return starting_vector.size();
    }

  private:

    std::vector<int> starting_vector;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
class VectorSum
{
  public:

    VectorSum(const A& other_a, const B& other_b):
      a{other_a}, b{other_b}
    {
      if (other_a.size() != other_b.size())
      {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"must be same sizes"};
      }
    }

    int operator[](const int i) const
    {
      return a[i] + b[i];
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
      return a.size();
    }

  private:

    const A a;
    const B b;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
VectorSum<A, B> operator+(const A v1, const B v2)
{
  return VectorSum<A, B>{v1, v2};
}

int main()
{
  Vector v1{{1,2,3,4,100}};
  Vector v2{{1,2,3,4,1}};
  Vector v3{{1,2,3,4,2}};
  Vector v4{{1,2,3,10,5}};

  VectorSum<VectorSum<VectorSum<Vector, Vector>, Vector>, Vector> sum {v1 + v2 + v3 + v4};

  std::cout << sum[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Very clear, thanks. May be you can implement a base class Expression which can simplify this VectorSum<VectorSum<VectorSum……> to Expression. I wonder if I will implement both matrix add and matrix multiply , should I implement two different Expression class , one for addition, the other for multiplication?

Comment: For matrix multiplication and addition add the operator+ and operator* in the same class.